Resampling an irregular time series in scilab
(Almost a total newbie with matlab/scilab so don't hit me too hard)
I need to process a signal coming from a SPICE simulation; I exported it a a text file and I have no issues in loading it up;
wav = readtable("signal.txt");

this gives me a useful table of data. The issue is that SPICE output is not sampled but the output interval depends on its own rules. So the table is a Time, Value sequence where time is not at regularly spaced interval; The time column is in seconds and I want to make a timeseries from the table; I spent a good amount of time to find the syntax for column addressing, too.
ts = timeseries(seconds(wav.time), wav(["I(R1)"]), "VariableNames", ["Time", "Current"]);

at last (and here's the problem) I want to resample it to a regular interval, say 0.5µs; from the help file I tried
rts = retime(ts, "regular", "linear", "TimeStep", seconds(0.5e-6));

however it doesn't work. It dies with
at line    26 of function isregular ( C:\Program Files\scilab-2024.0.0\modules\spreadsheet\macros\isregular.sci line 37 )
at line   618 of function retime    ( C:\Program Files\scilab-2024.0.0\modules\spreadsheet\macros\retime.sci line 629 )
isregular: Wrong value for input argument #2: "time" expected when the argument #1 is a duration.

which is internal code and I have no idea of what could it mean; I tried the matlab retime syntax but doesn't work.
Am I missing something here?
